# Can xcopy transfer the files in a subdirectory, but not the directories themselves?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Essentially, what I want to do is copy *.txt from the current directory as well as all the subdirectories. If I do `xcopy /s /e C:\source C:\dest`, it copies not just the files, but the directory structure as well. I need only the files to be copied, so `C:\dest` contains nothing but *.txt files. I checked the documentation for both xcopy and robocopy, but I couldn't find any parameters that allowed this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a FOR loop? It'll execute lots of copy commands, but give it a try:

```
FOR /R C:\source %%f IN (*.txt) DO xcopy /s "%%f" "C:\dest"
```

Comment: That command doesn't work. I get "f was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Thanks Kerrek, that fixed it. I also had to add some quotations so the command wouldn't break. I edited the answer, but it should go through peer review eventually.

Comment: @KerrekSB : Since we are strictly mentioning the format string, I guess the `/s` from `xcopy` could be omitted. Am I wrong?